# Android SDK Tools(Obsolete) for flutter not found in Android studio 3.6.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-sdk-manager

I am installing flutter in ubuntu 18.04 . I was going through official documentation stated [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux) .this documents suggests to Check Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) . A screenshot at official documentation suggested [Here](https://flutter.dev/assets/get-started/android/android-sdk-tools-7a3eaa161678e404dc0c570cc0f4921944a3413586bad47b5e1f585ddfefada0.png)

but in my Android studio 3.6.3 I'm not getting any option for Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) . attaching screenshot of what I am getting is as follows :

[image]

So How to resolve this issue to add flutter plugin in Android studio 3.6.3 .Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through welcome screen . Kindly go through

> Configure >> Plugins >> Marketplace >> flutter

Install the flutter plugin provided by flutter.dev

For further reference kindly check official documentation [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor) .